# Showing Onboard Keyboard On Lock Screen

Tags: keyboard, lock-screen, onboard

I have been playing around with the Onboard settings and even though I select the option "Show when unlocking the screen" from the settings the keyboard still doesn't appear when on screen lock. This appears to be an issue with Onboard and Ubuntu. Which is frustrating for me because I really like Ubuntu on my tablet but that is an important feature that doesn't seem to be working right and is holding it back.

I see there is another question pertaining to this exact same issue which hasn't received a response. So I am asking again, has anyone gotten this working? Any word from the developers (I can't seem to find any) on making this functionality available?

Answer (score 0):

So, on a whim I reinstalled Ubuntu from the latest version (14.10). I originally had 14.04 LTS. Nothing I did could get this to work (even reinstalling 14.04). So I downloaded the lastest release and did a clean install. And it looks as if the Devs fixed the issue in this latest release because now when I enable the option in Onboard settings, I get the keyboard pop up for logging in and from the lock screen.

An additional note. When you enable the lock screen option you get prompted to enable Accessibility features. This is the key for log in screen. Onboard doesn't automatically pop up at login. But in the task bar, you'll see the little Accessibility icon (a little man figure in a circle). touch that and you get the option to show the keyboard. This was also an issue with 14.04 LTS as it would never give me the accessibility icon in the task bar.